# invoke-super <interface method> vs invoke-interface <interface method>?

Tags: dalvik, smali

In Dex versions 037+, what is the difference in behavior between `invoke-super mid` and `invoke-interface mid` where `mid` is an **interface** method?

I am quoting the following from the Dalvik docs [1], but I am unable to make much sense out of it:

> In Dex files version 037 or later, if the method_id refers to an
>   interface method, `invoke-super` is used to invoke the *most specific,
>   non-overridden version of that method defined on that interface*. The
>   same method restrictions hold as for invoke-virtual. In Dex files
>   prior to version 037, having an interface method_id is illegal and
>   undefined.
>
> `invoke-interface` is used to invoke an interface method, that is, on an
>   object whose concrete class isn't known, using a method_id that refers
>   to an interface.

[1] https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dex version 37 adds support for default interface methods. So if you call invoke-super with something like `Lmy/interface;->someMethod()V`, it will search through the interface hierarchy to find the first interface that provides an implementation of that interface.

So, for a fuller example, let's say we have a few classes.

- `Lmy/superinterface;`
- `Lmy/interface;` which extends `Lmy/superinterface;`
- `Lmy/superclass;` which implements `Lmy/interface;`
- `Lmy/subclass;` which extends `Lmy/superclass;`

Let's say that `Lmy/superinterface;` defines a default implementation of `someMethod()V`, and both `Lmy/superclass;` and `Lmy/subclass;` provide their own implementation

If you have an object of `Lmy/subclass;` in v0, then

- `invoke-super {v0}, Lmy/interface;->someMethod()V` invokes the implementation from `Lmy/superinterface;`
- `invoke-super {v0}, Lmy/subclass;->someMethod()V` invokes the implementation from `Lmy/superclass;`
- `invoke-virtual {v0}, Lmy/subclass;->someMethod()V` invokes the implementation from `Lmy/subclass;`

Comment: Would `invoke-interface {v0}, Lmy/interface;->someMethod()V` invoke the implementation from `Lmy/subclass;` or the default implementation in `Lmy/superinterface;` ?

Comment: invoke-interface will invoke the "most specialized" implementation of the object it's being used with. so it would invoke the subclass implementation. If subclass didn't provide an implementation, it would invoke superclass's, and if it didn't provide an implementation it would invoke superinterface's